# Is there a way to use QCommandLineParser with an option followed by multiple values?

Tags: c++, qt, command-line-arguments

I need to make my app scan for a number of ports given as command line arguments and so far I have this:

```
    QCommandLineOption portScanOption(QStringList() << "p" << "target-port",
                QCoreApplication::translate("main", "Scan <port> for other instances"),
                QCoreApplication::translate("main", "port"));
    parser.addOption(portScanOption);
    parser.process(app);
    auto ports = parser.values(portScanOption); // do something with the ports
```

In order for this to work correctly, I need to pass the arguments like this: `-p 5000 -p 7000 -p 8000`.
I am looking for a way to make this work for the following input: `-p 5000 7000 8000`, but I haven't been able to find anything, not even in the official documentation. It's something quite trivial, so I expect Qt to have something like this. Do you guys know how it should be done?

Comment: I think [positional arguments](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html#addPositionalArgument) leads to what you trying to achieve. But couldn't find a good example:(

Comment: I looked into positional arguments as well, but they introduce a couple of problems. I would like the app to also work with multiple or no options if needed and in whatever order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already handled - the syntax you propose doesn't quite fit `QCommandLineParser`. Either use `-p 5000,7000,8000` or `-p "5000 7000 8000"`. All those ports will be the value of the port option, and you can then separate them with `split(QRegularExpression("[, ]"), Qt::SkipEmptyParts)` (that's `QString::split`). E.g.:

```
auto ports = parser.value("target-port")
             .split(QRegularExpression("[, ]"), Qt::SkipEmptyParts);
for (auto &portStr : ports) {
  bool ok = false;
  int port = portStr.toInt(&ok);
  if (!ok) continue;
  // use port value here
}
```

Alternatively, since the Qt source code is available, you could copy the command line parser source into your project, rename the class, and extend it to support the original syntax you had in mind.

Comment: I admit I didn't think at this at all, but adding a separator between the values and then splitting the string should just do the trick. Tweaking the Qt code at the moment is beyond my scope, so I will go with your first solution. Thank you!